# Basic Read from Firebase and load tableview with results (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I am trying to simply read my firebase data and populate a tableview with the information. For some reason, I can only seem to get the first item to appear. My firebase data looks like this:

```
{
"Filter by Color" : {
   "New Black" : {
      "Astrophyllite" : {
         "color" : "Black",
         "name" : "Astrophyllite",
         "properties" : "Astral Travel, Physic Protection"
      },
      "Onyx" : {
         "Properties" : "The Heals",
         "color" : "Black",
         "name" : "Onyx"
      }
   }
 }
}
```

My firebase permissions are set to read: true, write: false (I want public read permissions but no database changes from the application.

My Swift Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ref.child("Filter by Color").child("New Black").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var crystalList: [CrystalDefinitionClass] = []
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let crystals = CrystalDefinitionClass(snapshot: snapshot) {
                self.crystalArray.append(crystals)


            }
        }

        //            self.crystalArray = crystalList
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}
```

Below is the information for my table view stuff:

`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        //        return self.Crystal.count
        print(crystalArray.count)
        return crystalArray.count
    }`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let crystalDB = crystalArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = crystalDB.name

    return cell
}
```

This results in a single result from the database. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include a formatted snippet of your actual Firebase structure as TEXT please. You can get that from the Firebase Console->Export JSON.

Comment: Oh, and your code doesn't match your structure; your structure is */Filter by Color/Black* and your code is looking for */Filter by Color/New Black*. And also, you are re-using the variable name *snapshot* - it would be appropriate to name the snapshot inside the closure something like *childSnap* instead of the same name.

Comment: My json data:   {
  "Filter by Color" : {
    "Black" : {
      "Astrophyllite" : {
        "Color" : "Black",
        "Name" : "Astrophyllite",
        "Properties" : "Astral Travel, Psychic Protection"
      },
      "Black Quartz" : {
        "Color" : "Black",
        "Crystal" : "Black Quartz",
        "Name" : "Black Quartz"
      },
     }
  }
}

Comment: The "New Black" was an attempt to restructure some of the json data (I was thinking maybe I did something wrong with that. Now the snapshot reuse is something I didn't catch. I want to look into that. I was doing a lot of research online and trying to find different ways to accomplish this task so I may have over lapped some of it. The strange thing is, the first item appears in the tableview but that is it. I tried moving it to view will appear and then running a secondary reload() in view did load (thinking that maybe it was only loading one) but no go

Comment: ugh. No. Please update your **question** with the Firebase structure. Trying to read that in comments is very challenging.

Comment: ah, apologies on that. I was wondering why it wouldn't take in my response. Updated now

Comment: The issue is your first node has *properties* and the second node has *Properties*. Firebase is case sensitive for those keys so they need to be consistent.

Comment: That was it. I, for some reason, didn't realize that if any of the fields were missing a piece of the information, they would not appear. If you want to paste that response into an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has case sensitive keys so in this case within the New Black node, the first child node has 'properties'

```
  "Astrophyllite" : {
     "color" : "Black",
     "name" : "Astrophyllite",
     "properties" : "Astral Travel, Physic Protection"
  },
```

and the second child node has 'Properties'

```
  "Onyx" : {
     "Properties" : "The Heals",
     "color" : "Black",
     "name" : "Onyx"
  }
```

Firebase would consider these two different keys. In general, it's critical that child node keys remain consistent across the child nodes so they can be properly read and queried.